# Is there an observable Dunning-Kruger-style effect whereby the most difficult languages for a student to learn are initially considered easy?

Tags: reference-request, learning-psychology

When I started learning Chinese, overconfidence led to me thinking it was "easy".  However as I progress, I realize not only how little I know, but also how ignorant I was early on: I was completely unaware of huge aspects of the Chinese language.  Having studied for years, I now feel fairly comfortable with the common assessment that Chinese is one of the hardest languages to learn as a native English speaker.

However, I recall early on talking to other people also learning Chinese who shared my assessment as Chinese as "easy".  It seems I was not the only one with overconfidence.  Hence...

**Question**: Is there an observable Dunning-Kruger-style effect whereby the most difficult languages for a student to learn are initially considered easy?

I'm wondering what research has been done on this topic.  (To be clear, this question is not limited to learning Chinese as a native English speaker: that's just my motivation for asking.)  I found one paper, but it's behind a paywall so I can only see this:

> High performers aligned their self-ratings with their actual performance over time.  In contrast, **low performers showed limited progress towards alignment**.
> <sub>Saitoa, Trofimovich, Abe, In'nami, [*Dunning-Kruger effect in second language speech learning: How does self perception align with other perception over time?*](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.lindif.2020.101849), Learning and Individual Differences, 2020.</sub>

So I don't know what how "alignment" is defined, and what this really means, but it seems to indicate that beginners make inaccurate assessments of their language level.